# Removing Android toolbar bar on Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have two issues with a Sencha Touch application, first is how do I remove the top bar highlighted in red, second is, when I press the back from above bar it goes back fine but when I press the phone's back button it takes me out of application, what can I do? Look at the picture below

[image]

I have already tried using  navigationBar:hidden or false and autoMaximize:true,  also about back button thing I don't have any idea so please suggest me something.

Comment: maybe if your share your code :)

Comment: These are two different issues, you should have made two separate questions.

Comment: @John Doe Has my answer been helpful? Could you give some feedback?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Question 1)**

I guess you are using Sencha native packaging, and you have encountered this bug: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?259817-3.1.0.256-Strange-Android-Titlebar-on-native-Apps/page2

Quote from richardvd user of Sencha Touch Forums:

> This is the Android TitleBar, you can remove it by adding an attribute
>   to your base AndroidManifest.xml.
>
> In my case this file is located here:
>   C:\ext\Sencha\Cmd\3.1.1.274\stbuild\st-res\android\AndroidManifest.xml
>
> Open it and add this attribute to the application field:
>   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

**Question 2)**

You can control the back button behaviour from Javascript with Cordova/Phonegap:

> document.addEventListener("backbutton", yourCallbackFunction, false);

Source: [PhoneGap documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#backbutton)

Comment: I'm glad. The best way to thank me would be giving me some credit accepting my answer: read this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Comment: I tried this solution but it still packs with the title bar. I am using the Sencha Command Version : 4.0.1.45 with the Sencha Architect. Can anyone please help me out ?.